# how to make a table from the columns of other tables in bash?

Tags: bash, dataframe

Hello I have 50 tables in tsv format all with the same column names in the same order:

e.g.

```
cat sample1.tsv | head -4
```

| name | coverage | ID | bases | reads | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vir1 | 0.535 | 3rf | 1252 | 53 | 11424 |
| vir2 | 0.124 | 2ds | 7534 | 152 | 63221 |
| vir3 | 0.643 | 6tf | 3341 | 73 | 21142 |

I want to elaborate a table from the "reads" column (5th column) from the 50 tables. The name column have the same values and same order along the 50 tables

Desired output:

```
cat reads_table.tsv | head -4
```

| names | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 | sample4 | sample5 | sample50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vir1 | 53 | 742 | 42 | 242 | 42 | 342 |
| vir2 | 152 | 212 | 512 | 21 | 74 | 41 |
| vir3 | 73 | 13 | 172 | 42 | 142 | 123 |

I was thinking on doing this by saving the reads column (the 5th column in all tables) to an array and using `paste` bash function to paste the columns and save them to a new empty file called "reads_table.tsv" but I don't know how to do this on bash.

This is what I tried in a first instance:

```
for i in *.tsv 
do 
reads=$(awk '{print $5}' $i)
sed -i 's/$/\t$reads/' $i >> reads_table.tsv
done
```

Comment: Are the names (the data in the first column) in the same order in all files?

Comment: yes, the elements in the name column are in the same order.

Comment: In your code `reads` will be filled with many lines, One approach would be filling a multi dimensional array in `awk` like `awk '{ reads[$FILENAME][$1]=$5 } END { ..}' *.tsv`. 
The `sed` command with the `-i` parameter (changing the inputfile) and redirecting to another won't work.

Comment: `cat sample1.tsv | head -4 ` does not produce the html table output you show. `.tsv` generally refers to *tab-separated-values*. Simply include `\`\`\`none` above the actual output and `\`\`\`` below it to format it as fixed text in your question (those are back-ticks -- or just indent it all by 4-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

Created some input files to match OP's expected output:

```
$ head sample*.tsv
==> sample1.tsv <==
name    coverage        ID      bases   reads   length
vir1    0.535   3rf     1252    53      11424
vir2    0.124   2ds     7534    152     63221
vir3    0.643   6tf     3341    73      21142

==> sample2.tsv <==
name    coverage        ID      bases   reads   length
vir1    0.535   3rf     1252    742     11424
vir2    0.124   2ds     7534    212     63221
vir3    0.643   6tf     3341    13      21142

==> sample3.tsv <==
name    coverage        ID      bases   reads   length
vir1    0.535   3rf     1252    42      11424
vir2    0.124   2ds     7534    512     63221
vir3    0.643   6tf     3341    172     21142

==> sample4.tsv <==
name    coverage        ID      bases   reads   length
vir1    0.535   3rf     1252    242     11424
vir2    0.124   2ds     7534    21      63221
vir3    0.643   6tf     3341    42      21142

==> sample5.tsv <==
name    coverage        ID      bases   reads   length
vir1    0.535   3rf     1252    42      11424
vir2    0.124   2ds     7534    74      63221
vir3    0.643   6tf     3341    142     21142

==> sample50.tsv <==
name    coverage        ID      bases   reads   length
vir1    0.535   3rf     1252    342     11424
vir2    0.124   2ds     7534    41      63221
vir3    0.643   6tf     3341    123     21142
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }
FNR==NR { lines[FNR]=$1 }                        # save 1st column ("name") of 1st file
FNR==1  { split(FILENAME,a,".")                  # 1st row of each file: split FILENAME
          lines[FNR]=lines[FNR] OFS a[1]         # save FILENAME (sans ".tsv")
          next
        }
        { lines[FNR]=lines[FNR] OFS $5 }         # rest of rows in file: append tjhe 5th column to our output lines
END     { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++)                   # loop through rows and ...
              print lines[i]                     # print the associated line to stdout
        }
' $(find . -name "sample*.tsv" -printf "%f\n" | sort -V ) > reads_table.tsv
```

**NOTES:**

- the `find/sort` is required to insure the files are fed to `awk` in `V`ersion sort order (eg, `sample3.tsv` comes before `sample21.tsv`)
- the `printf %f\n` removes the leading `.\` from the filename (otherwise we could remove in the `awk` script)
- the `-V` option tells `sort` to run a `V`ersion sort

This generates:

```
name    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample50
vir1    53      742     42      242     42      342
vir2    152     212     512     21      74      41
vir3    73      13      172     42      142     123
```

Comment: Excellent readable `awk` script and GEM award for Going the Extra Mile creating the sample input.